# Why does mongoose model's hasOwnProperty return false when property does exist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I have this code :

```
user.findOne( { 'email' : email }, function( err, User )
            {
                if ( err )
                {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if ( !User )
                {
                    return done(null, false, { error : "User not found"});
                }
                if ( !User.hasOwnProperty('local') || !User.local.hasOwnProperty('password') )
                {
                    console.log("here: " + User.hasOwnProperty('local')); // displays here: false
                }
                if ( !User.validPass(password) )
                {
                    return done(null, false, { error : "Incorrect Password"});
                }
                return done(null, User);
            });
```

Since the app supports other kinds of authentication, I have a user model that has nested object called local which looks like

```
local : { password : "USERS_PASSWORD" }
```

So during login I want to check whether the user has provided a password but I encountered this interesting problem. 
My test object looks like this:

```
{ _id: 5569ac206afebed8d2d9e11e,
email: 'test@example.com',
phno: '1234567890',
gender: 'female',
dob: Wed May 20 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
name: 'Test Account',
__v: 0,
local: { password: '$2a$07$gytktl7BsmhM8mkuh6JVc3Bs/my7Jz9D0KBcDuKh01S' } }
```

but `console.log("here: " + User.hasOwnProperty('local'));` prints `here: false`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How are User and user defined? Are you assuming they are the same?

Comment: Nope, they are not same 
One is `var user = require('../models/user');` which is the mongoose model 
The other one is the callback argument in the above code

Comment: ok, this is a bit confusing. Usually you should only use things that start with a capital letter for constructors.

Comment: even more confusing is `user` actually is a constructor, while `User` is not. ;)

Comment: Oh, didnt know that.. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps `local` exists on the prototype and not on the actual object instance?

Comment: How is your model defined? how is `local` populated?

Comment: Are you sure that object specified is really User at the point in question? Can you log User just before the "here" line?

Comment: okay I did this 
    console.log(User);
    console.log("here: " + User.hasOwnProperty('local'));
And I got this output:
    { _id: 5569ac206afebed8d2d9e11e,
  email: 'test@example.com',
  phno: '1234567890',
  gender: 'female',
  dob: Wed May 20 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
  name: 'Test Account',
  __v: 0,
  local: { password: '$2a$07$gyht0aktl7BsmhMGDo8mkuh6JVc3Bs/my7Jz59D0KBcDuZLYKh01S' } }
here: false

Comment: By how is it defined, i mean, i want to see **'../models/user'**

Comment: like this: 
`var schema = mongoose.Schema({

    name : String,
    dob : Date,
    gender : String,
    phno : String,
    email : String,

    local : {
        password : String
    }

});`

Comment: Somehow `console.log("here: " + user.local.hasOwnProperty('password'));` prints out **here: true** .. Is mongoose.model().prototype.hasOwnProperty different from Object.hasOwnProperty

Comment: Othe rthan the fact that those are two different objects, no.

Comment: Something is wrong somewhere else but I am not able to figure it out. I think I'll put it in try..catch for now

Comment: Why not just check for `"local" in User`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's because the document object you get back from mongoose doesn't access the properties directly. It uses the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) chain hence [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) returning false (I am simplifying this greatly).

You can do one of two things: use [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) to convert it to a plain object and then your checks will work as is:

```
var userPOJO = User.toObject();
if ( !(userPOJO.hasOwnProperty('local') && userPOJO.local.hasOwnProperty('password')) ) {...}
```

OR you can just check for values directly:

```
if ( !(User.local && User.local.password) ) {...}
```

Since neither properties can have a falsy value it should work for testing if they are populated.

EDIT: Another check I forgot to mention is to use Mongoose's built in [`get` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get):

```
if (!User.get('local.password')) {...}
```

Comment: Second method did not work (returned false even for defined properties), but using `.toObject()` then `.hasOwnProperty(...)` was Ok. Thanks !

Comment: @FrostyZ I am a bit confused by that. Another check I forgot to mention is to use Mongoose's built in [`get` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get): `if (!User.get('local.password')) {...}`. Maybe that would be better for you?

Comment: Works as expected with `.get(...)` (and even better than `hasOwnProperty()` because `get()` is able to detect properties containing empty objects, whereas `hasOwnProperty()` method isn't, probably due to the `.toObject()` conversion). Thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the data and not the other Mongoose magic such as `.save()`, `.remove()` etc then the most simple way would be to use [`.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

```
user.findOne( { 'email' : email }, function( err, User ).lean()
            {
                if ( err )
                {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if ( !User )
                {
                    return done(null, false, { error : "User not found"});
                }
                if ( !User.hasOwnProperty('local') || !User.local.hasOwnProperty('password') )
                {
                    console.log("here: " + User.hasOwnProperty('local')); // Should now be "here: true"
                }
                if ( !User.validPass(password) )
                {
                    return done(null, false, { error : "Incorrect Password"});
                }
                return done(null, User);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also detach the returned JSON from MongoDB Schema - `JSONuser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(User))` - and then use JSONuser freely getting, changing or adding, any of its properties.