# Why does obj.prop return true when obj.hasOwnProperty('prop') returns false?

Tags: javascript, properties

I'm working with NodeJS and Mongoose. I get an array of arrays from the database (let's call it `results[][]`).

I just want to test if my objects contained in each arrays have the property **game_id** (a random positive integer).

I tried a simple condition like I always do:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    if(results[i][0].hasOwnProperty('game_id')) {
        console.log('OK ?');
    }
}
```

But I never passed the condition... That was weird because if I dump the object I see the **game_id** property.

So I tried this:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    if(results[i][0].hasOwnProperty('game_id')) {
        console.log('[' + i + '] Test 1: ' + results[i][0].game_id);
    }
    if(results[i][0].game_id) {
        console.log('[' + i + '] Test 2: ' + results[i][0].game_id);
    }
}
```

And get:

```
[0] Test 2: 123
[1] Test 2: 456
[2] Test 2: 789
[3] Test 2: 1011
```

And I don't get it...

Why `results[i][0].hasOwnProperty('game_id')` returns false when `results[i][0].game_id` is true? What's going on there?

Comment: Any inheritance in your objects? Can you reproduce this issue in a simple fiddle?

Comment: Add results JSON here.

Comment: @Jamiec No I can't because of mongoose. I found the same kind of question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923378/why-does-mongoose-models-hasownproperty-return-false-when-property-does-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think that this would occur is if the `game_id` property came in through a prototype chain. `hasOwnProperty` will return false for the property if it is not part of the *actual object being enumerated*, but it may well still have a property/value from a prototype.

The following code demonstrates this:

```js
function CreateObject(){    
}
CreateObject.prototype = {
       game_id:123
    };

var arr = [
 new CreateObject(), new CreateObject()
];

for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(arr[i].hasOwnProperty('game_id')) {
        console.log('[' + i + '] Test 1: ' + arr[i].game_id);   // not logged
    }
    if(arr[i].game_id) {
        console.log('[' + i + '] Test 2: ' + arr[i].game_id); // logged
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right. It's because of Mongoose schema. There's already an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923378/why-does-mongoose-models-hasownproperty-return-false-when-property-does-exist