# hasOwnProperty not working in pre validate in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a schema -

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  author: {type:String,required:true},
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

PostSchema.pre('validate',function(next){
    console.log("Pre validate document printing - ");
    console.log(this);
    console.log("Pre validate called. Title : ",this._id);
    console.log("Author is : ",this.author);
    console.log("hasOwnProperty : ",this.hasOwnProperty("author"));
    console.log("this.author==\'\' : ",this.author=='');
    if(!(this.hasOwnProperty("author"))||this.author==''){
        console.log("Here");
        this.author="Hacked";
    }
    next();
});
```

In my routes -

```
router.post('/posts', auth,function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("Before - ");
    var post = new Post(req.body);
    post.upvotes="2";
    console.log(post);
    post.author="Meseeks";
    console.log("After - ");
    console.log(post);
    console.log("Creating author");
    //post.author = req.payload.username;
    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){return next(err);}
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

The Nodejs Logs - print this -

```
Before - 
{ title: 'im mr meeseeks',
  link: null,
  _id: 589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00,
  comments: [],
  upvotes: 2 }
After - 
{ author: 'Meseeks',
  title: 'im mr meeseeks',
  link: null,
  _id: 589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00,
  comments: [],
  upvotes: 2 }
Creating author
Pre validate document printing - 
{ author: 'Meseeks',
  title: 'im mr meeseeks',
  link: null,
  _id: 589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00,
  comments: [],
  upvotes: 2 }
Pre validate called. Title :  589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00
Author is :  Meseeks
hasOwnProperty :  false
this.author=='' :  false
Here
Post validate called. Title :  589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00
Pre save called. Title :  589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00
Post save called. Title :  589f0f3ddf781803b459dc00
```

I am setting the author manually to in my Router . However the pre init function isn't able to verify if the property "author" exists in the object. How is this possible? Am i doing something wrong??

How do I check if that property exists in pre init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point in code is "this" not an Object, just a prototype. More explanation and workarounds are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30926660/7564182).